# UISearchBar Filter UITableView with NSPredicate filter from array of dictionary with multiple Keys

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, nspredicate

I am setting up a `UISearchBar` on `UITableView`. `UITableViewCell` has 3 `UIlabel` and data is in `NSArray` with Dictionaries in it with three keys `"name", "phone", "email"`
I have filtered the table but it filters by name or email or phone 
I want to filter with all three keys

tried all NSCoumpound Predicate but failed 
tried filter

```
extension CleanerListViewController: UISearchBarDelegate{
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        let formatString = "(name contains[c] %@)"
        filterList = cleanerList.filter { NSPredicate(format: formatString, searchText).evaluate(with: $0) } as NSArray

        if searchText.count == 0{
            filterList = cleanerList
        }
        self.tblCleanerList.reloadData()
    }
}
```

[image: ScreenShot]

The only above code works for single keys 
any help will be appreciated  please don't a negative vote

Comment: can you explain your expected result with example

Comment: `let keys = ["name", "phone", "email"]; let subPredicates = keys.map({ NSPredicate(format: "%K CONTAINS[c] %@", $0, searchText) }); let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: subPredicates)`? But why using NSPredicate? why not use directly `filter({})` Also, why using `NSArray`?

Comment: Ok I change it to Array tried to use by filter but unable to doo

Comment: @Asif result should be text searched in the search bar

Comment: @Larme thanx this really works  and if u have any better and efficient approach please share

Comment: What's your `cleanerList`'s type? [[String : String]]? Larme's predicates solve your issue  but you can do this easier using `filter({})`, like told above

Comment: now my problem is solved with the help of @Larme
@LokSN but I was unable to do with Filter if u can help 
type of cleaner filter is ```Array<Any>```

Comment: Assuming you have an `Array<Any>` that supposedly contains `[String: String]` with your key-pair values, you can also do it using filter:-
`yourAnyArray.filter({($0 as! [String : String]).values.map({$0.contains("searchString")}).contains(true)})`. Not sure if this is more efficient, but just another way to get it done

Comment: Let me know if this works...

Comment: i will surely try bro

Comment: @MeetIosDeveloper Don't use `Array<Any>`. Use at least `Array<[String: Any]>`. Even better, parse your data with your own model, so it will be `Array<MyModel>` (or `[Model]`). Also, `contains()` is case sensitive, while the predicate used with `[c]` was case INcensitive. And the `.contains(true)` is for what reason @LokSN

Comment: @Meet Ios Developer Yes, don't use Array<Any>. You're better off using structs for your custom types instead of dictionaries and it will simplify things a lot. @Larme, my bad, I could have used `range` with `.insensitive` as an option. I've used the `.contains(true)` as the map returns me `[Bool]` for each key-pair value and I have to filter out of them

Answer (score 0):

```
extension CleanerListViewController: UISearchBarDelegate{
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        if searchText.isEmpty {
            filterList = cleanerList
        } else {
            let keys = ["name", "phone", "email"]
            let subPredicates = keys.map({ NSPredicate(format: "%K CONTAINS[c] %@", $0, searchText) })
            let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: subPredicates)
            filterList = cleanerList.filter { predicate.evaluate(with: $0) } as NSArray
        }

        self.tblCleanerList.reloadData()
    }
}
```